# Applying pre trained facebook/bart-large-cnn for text summarization in python

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, huggingface-transformers, summarization, huggingface-tokenizers

I am in a situation where I am working with huggingface transformers and have got some insights into it. I am working with the facebook/bart-large-cnn model to perform text summarisation for my project and I am using the following code as of now to do some tests:

```
text = """
Justin Timberlake and Jessica Biel, welcome to parenthood. 
The celebrity couple announced the arrival of their son, Silas Randall Timberlake, in 
statements to People."""

from transformers import pipeline
smr_bart = pipeline(task="summarization", model="facebook/bart-large-cnn")
smbart = smr_bart(text, max_length=150)
print(smbart[0]['summary_text'])
```

The small peice of code is actually giving me a very good summary of the text. But my ask is that how can I apply the same pre trained model on top of my dataframe column. My dataframe looks like this:

```
ID        Lang          Text
1         EN            some long text here...
2         EN            some long text here...
3         EN            some long text here...
```

.... and so on for 50K rows

Now I want to apply the pre trained model to the col Text to generate a new column df['summary'] from it and the resultant dataframe should look like:

```
ID        Lang         Text                              Summary
1         EN            some long text here...           Text summary goes here...
2         EN            some long text here...           Text summary goes here...
3         EN            some long text here...           Text summary goes here...
```

How can I achieve this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Aren’t you just asking how to apply a function to every value in a Series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something you can always do is utilizing the dataframe [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([('EN',text)]*10, columns=['Lang','Text'])

df['summary'] = df.apply(lambda x: smr_bart(x['Text'], max_length=150)[0]['summary_text'] , axis=1)

df.head(3)
```

Output:

```
    Lang    Text                                                summary
0   EN      \nJustin Timberlake and Jessica Biel, welcome ...   The celebrity couple announced the arrival of ...
1   EN      \nJustin Timberlake and Jessica Biel, welcome ...   The celebrity couple announced the arrival of ...
2   EN      \nJustin Timberlake and Jessica Biel, welcome ...   The celebrity couple announced the arrival of ...
```

That is a bit inefficient because the pipeline will be called for every row (execution time 2 minutes and 16 seconds). Therefore I recommend to cast the `Text` column to a list and pass it to the pipeline directly (execution time 41 seconds):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([('EN',text)]*10, columns=['Lang','Text'])

df['summary'] = [x['summary_text'] for x in smr_bart(df['Text'].tolist(), max_length=150)]

df.head(3)
```

Output:

```
    Lang    Text                                                summary
0   EN      \nJustin Timberlake and Jessica Biel, welcome ...   The celebrity couple announced the arrival of ...
1   EN      \nJustin Timberlake and Jessica Biel, welcome ...   The celebrity couple announced the arrival of ...
2   EN      \nJustin Timberlake and Jessica Biel, welcome ...   The celebrity couple announced the arrival of ...
```